# How to restart python multi-thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to design a control interface for my system which sends and receives some data through serial link. My searches related to GUI design took me to understand the "multi-threading" issue and code below shows the latest position I arrived.

This indicates similar parts (e.g try, run) with the ones I've seen on example GUIs. I planned to convert this to a GUI, once I understand how it exactly works.

So the problem is after I start, stop the code below I can't restart it again. Because, as I understand, multi-threading features only one cycle: start, stop and quit. I mean it doesn't accept start command after stop.

My question is how I can make this code to accept start after stopping?

Best wishes

```
import threading, random, time    
class process(threading.Thread):        
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)          
    def run(self):          
        self.leave  = 0 
        print("\n it's running ...\n\n")            
        while self.leave != 1:  
            print "Done!"
            time.sleep(1)   

operate = process()    

while True:
    inputt = input("   START : 1 \n   STOP\t : 0 \n   QUIT\t : 2 \n")       
    try:
        if int(inputt) == 1:
            operate.start()             
        elif int(inputt) == 0:
            operate.leave = 1               
        elif int(inputt) == 2:
            break

    except:
        print(" Wrong input, try egain...\n")
```

Comment: What does it mean to "reset" and "restart" the thread? Why do you ask  "[h]ow to restart python GUI", then you suggest you don't want to restar the GUI and there is nothing GUI-related in your code?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking. You want to restart a process in another thread using tkinter GUI, is that it?

Comment: create process inside `while True`, not before. Or don't leave thread when keep it running - putting code is some `while True` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `process` inside `while True` loop

```
    if int(inputt) == 1:
        operate = process()    
        operate.start()
```

It should work.

... but your code may need other changes to make it safer - you will have to check if process exists before you try to stop it. You could use `operate = None` to control it.

```
import threading
import random
import time    


class Process(threading.Thread):        

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)          

    def run(self):          
        self.leave = False
        print("\n it's running ...\n\n")            
        while self.leave == False:  
            print("Done!")
            time.sleep(1)   

operate = None

while True:
    inputt = input("   START : 1 \n   STOP\t : 0 \n   QUIT\t : 2 \n")       
    try:
        if int(inputt) == 1:
            if operate is None:
                operate = Process()    
                operate.start()             
        elif int(inputt) == 0:
            if operate is not None:
                operate.leave = True
                operate.join() # wait on process end
                operate = None
        elif int(inputt) == 2:
            if operate is not None:
                operate.leave = True
                operate.join() # wait on process end
            break
    except:
        print(" Wrong input, try egain...\n")
```

---

Other method is not to leave `run()` when you set `leave = True` but keep running thead. You would need two loops.

```
 def run(self):          
    self.leave = False
    self.stoped = False
    print("\n it's running ...\n\n")            
    while self.leave == False:  
        while self.stoped == False:
             print("Done!")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Dear @furas many thanks :)) this is exactly what I tried to ask.